# Page.IsPostBack equivalent in PHP

Tags: php, post

When working on the same page which accepts Post data, it is good to know whether there is a special function like the one in Asp.NET such as `Page.IsPostBack`. Maybe I could use `isset($_POST)` but I am thinking there could be a special function for that.

So I want to process the post data under that function give alerts during processing the post data, otherwise it is just a page request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am always using

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

Answer (score 5):

<strike>Maybe you could use:</strike>

`if (count($_POST))`

as this will return either 0 or 1.

Or:

```
// Determine whether the page was requested via GET or POST.
function isPostBack() { 
    return ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST');
}
```

Comment: `count($_POST)` is not reliable. You can call a page via POST method but not send any variables; `count($_POST)` will be `0` in that case.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a case that calls for PHP filter input (http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php), but I ended up going with `strtolower(filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD')) == 'post'`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a function specifically for that. I would just do `count($_POST)` to check if the `$_POST` array contains anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isPostBack()
{
   return (count($_POST) > 1);
}
```